# spring cloud openfeign upload file error, how to solve?

Tags: java, spring

when it use `@requestpart` annotation it yields the error

> No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["file"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"])

When I use `@requestparam` annotation it yields the error `Current request is not a multipart request`

How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Please post code in a formatted code block, not a screenshot: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)